# ¿Cómo agregar correctamente el último valor del índice de una df a otra df vacía? Relacionado a Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, depuración, index, typeerror

Digamos que tengo el siguiente df vacío llamado `df_pnl`, después de llamarlo produce el siguiente resultado:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [PnL, Type of Trade, ROI, Cumulative ROI, Cumulative Investment]
Index: []
```

Si ejecutas `df_pnl.index[-1:]`, produce el siguiente resultado:

```
Index([], dtype='object', name='End Date')
```

Ahora, hay otro df llamado `df_chosen_trading_pair` que muestra los siguientes datos como salida cuando es llamado:

```
                         Close Price 
End Date                             
2022-06-25 02:29:59.999        11.21
2022-06-25 02:59:59.999        11.19
2022-06-25 03:29:59.999        11.25
2022-06-25 03:59:59.999        11.37
2022-06-25 04:29:59.999        11.34
                             ...    
2022-06-27 04:59:59.999        10.96
2022-06-27 05:29:59.999        10.80
2022-06-27 05:59:59.999        10.82
2022-06-27 06:29:59.999        10.84
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999        10.88

[106 rows x 1 columns]
```

Si ejecuta `df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`, produce el siguiente resultado:

```
'2022-06-27 06:59:59.999'
```

Si ejecuta `type(df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1])`, produce el siguiente resultado:

```
str
```

Necesito agregar el valor de `df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]` a `df_pnl.index[-1:]` para obtener el siguiente resultado al llamar la `df_pnl`:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```

Intenté las siguientes líneas y ninguna de ellas funcionó:

> **In[124]:** `df_pnl.index[0:] = df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

> **In[125]:** `df_pnl["End Date"][-1] = df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1]`

> KeyError: 'End Date'

¿Me pueden ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, creo que por accidente encontré mi solución:

> **In [167]:** `df_pnl.loc[df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-1], :] = None`

Genera:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```

Además, me di cuenta que sí por ejemplo deseo agregar una nueva fila usando el penúltimo valor index de `df_chosen_trading_pair`, simplemente se debe cambiar el valor dentro del arreglo, así:

> **In [167]:** `df_pnl.loc[df_chosen_trading_pair.index[-2], :] = None`

Genera:

```
                         PnL   Type of Trade  ROI  Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
End Date                             
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN

2022-06-27 06:29:59.999  NaN             NaN  NaN             NaN                    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Buen día,

Para hacerlo, el `dataframe` vacío debe tener las columnas que necesitas

Luego puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) para agregar el índice del otro `dataframe`

Con un archivo de prueba "sample.csv" con los datos que pusiste en tu pregunta cree el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df_e = pd.DataFrame(columns=['End Date', 'PnL', 'Type of Trade', 'ROI', 'Cumulative ROI', 'Cumulative Investment'])
df_e.set_index('End Date')

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', index_col = 'End Date')

df_e = df_e.reindex([df.index[-1]])
```

Al imprimir `df_e` obtenemos:

```
End Date                PnL Type of Trade   ROI Cumulative ROI  Cumulative Investment
2022-06-27 06:59:59.999 NaN NaN             NaN NaN             NaN        NaN
```

Comment: ¡Hola! Gracias por tu solución, te dejaré el upvote porque respondiste más rápido que yo jeje.

Comment: Buen día, que bien que encontraste la respuesta a tu pregunta! Por favor acepta tu respuesta como correcta, dejaré esta aquí para mostrar otra forma de hacerlo. Saludos!